# How do I identify stale / dead branches in git?

Tags: git

I maintain a git repository which has a hundred or so branches on the central repository. Many of these branches were created for some purpose long served and are now inactive. Some branches might have to stay for a reason (e.g. they are release branches) but many of the others could be deleted.

I want a script that generates a report of each branch, sorted by last commit activity and also to tag that branch with a *** if the branch was merged into our mainline "develop" branch.

So a sample output might be:

```
origin/develop          10 minutes ago
origin/feature/X        1 day ago
origin/feature/Y    *** 35 days ago 
origin/feature/Z        70 days ago
```

So I can email out owners of Y and Z and tell them to delete their branches. I can also say to Y that their branch was merged to develop.

I assume I can test for a merge by finding the sha1 of final commit on the branch and do a "git branch --contains hashcode" on it.

Is there a script out there which would serve my purpose already?

Comment: Beware that just because your copy of the repo says that the last commit on a branch was 70 days ago doesn't mean that there haven't been more commits made in somebody else's clone of the repo. It only means that there have been no new commits pushed into your copy of the repo in that period... I'm not sure this sounds like a good idea in a DVCS scenario, although if you do delete something that is still active, their next push will just put it back...

Comment: My intention is to email the owners and gently remind them to delete their own branches rather than do it for them, although I could see me deleting a branch if the person leaves the company or its obvious the branch is dead. If they really do have the branch on their machine, then they can just push it again of course.

Comment: It sounds like you know/knew enough to write this script yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I not certain about identifying repos that haven't been committed to in awhile, but as for identifying branches that have *already been merged*, here are a few commands...

(All code below lifted from [Steve Harman's blog post](http://stevenharman.net/git-clean-delete-already-merged-branches), go there fore more information.)

To delete local branches which have already been merged into master:

```
(First, check out master.  Then...)
$ git branch --merged master | grep -v "\* master" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

You can omit the master branch argument to remove local branches which have already been merged into the current HEAD:

```
$ git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

Comment: "git branch -d" is dangerous , it will delete branches

Comment: That's the point LOL